# Problems with installing gsl, nothing works

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, gsl

I have been having troubles for some time now installing gsl on ubuntu. I followed this guide:
http://www.brianomeara.info/tutorials/brownie/gsl
with version 1.15. did ./configure, make install, etc.
Now im trying to run an example:

http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~ndjw1/teaching/sim/gsl.html

the compile command is
gcc -I/usr/include/gsl -lgsl -lgslblasnative gsl_test.c -o gsl_test

and the error I get is:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgslblasnative

I have also tried other examples before with the same error, that it cant find the libraries im trying to access. I am really a newbie to compiling/linking so I do not know what the parameters in these commands mean. And is there any way to check if the installation was successfully completed?

Comment: What's the output of `locate gslblasnative`?

Comment: No output. (executed the command in the gsl folder)

Comment: You might try `-lgslblas` instead of `-lgslblasnative`.

Comment: I get the same error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgslblas

Comment: One more. Try `-lgslcblas` (with a `c`) instead of `-lgslblasnative`. I think one of your problems is the instructions for the site you linked are for version 0.7 of `gsl` which may not be the same for the version you're using.

Comment: Not working, but a different error:/tmp/ccFsFomJ.o: In function `main':
gsl_test.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_mt19937'
gsl_test.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `gsl_rng_alloc'
gsl_test.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `gsl_ran_gaussian'
gsl_test.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `gsl_ran_gamma'

Comment: To confirm you're using the command `gcc -I/usr/include/gsl -lgsl -lgslcblas gsl_test.c -o gsl_test`?

Comment: I believe that there might be a problem with my installation of gsl, but I do not know how to check that...